# start activity without launching the application

Tags: android, android-activity, service

Here is the use case:
1. User logs into the app and presses the hardware home button and app is sent to background
2. I run a handler in the background to check if the inactivity time out is 5 mins. Then I need to call the logout API and start the loginactivity, **Without launching or bringing the app to foreground**
Here is what I have tried

```
if (!mIsAppInForeground) {
            Log.d("App in background", "App in background and timing out");

            activity.startService(new Intent(activity,LogOutBackGroundService.class).addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK ));

        }

public class LogOutBackGroundService extends Service {

    public static final String HAS_SIGNED_OUT = "hasSignedOut";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        intent.putExtra(HAS_SIGNED_OUT, true);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The app is timing out properly and login activity is being launched, but the app is being brought to foreground (i.e app is being launched). I want this to happen in the background only. Only when the user relaunches the app, he should see the login screen again

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Of course the `LoginActivity` is being launched - you're calling `startActivity(...)` from your `Service`. Why don't you simply just check to see if the user is logged in each time they manually start your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startactivity(intent)` pops up the backstack activity or creates a new one if it doesn't exist.. so your solution is there is `onResume()` and `onPause()`.. `onPause()` is called when you the activity is gone, `onResume()` is called when you see the activity, so my advice to you is create a boolean, it can be in a singleton class

```
public class MySingletonClass {
  public static boolean startloginpage; // by default its false
 }
```

then you in mainactivity or the activity that the user will launch or come back to, put the code in its onresume

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if(MySingletonClass.startloginpage){ //check if your boolean is true
        // if it checks out then call do what you want to do when the user times run out
    }else{
      // if it doesn't check out continue without telling user to login,
   }
}
```

in your service remove the intent code and put this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    intent.putExtra(HAS_SIGNED_OUT, true);
    MySingletonClass.startloginpage = true;
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a singleton to maintain a boolean? Why not just use `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: oh yes,Sir, but, i feel like `sharedPreference` is cheap, not in relation to memory, but its nowadays-flaw, the end user gets a feel of how your app gets down about its business, and also with this, then the user can bypass his re-login mechanism anytime, so i think handling it in a class is better. that's my thoughts though.@Squonk

Comment: @Elitz couldn't understand what you meant here if(MySingletonClass.startloginpage){ //check if its true
        // if it checks out then do your job for login
    }else{
      // if it doesn't check out continue without telling user to login

Comment: you are trying to check if the user timeout duration has elapsed, so you start the loginactivity, and that's a sample of what that code will do, check if the time has elapsed which is _true_ then execute the loginactivity if not continue without calling the loginactivity.. understand now? if the loginacitvity is your launcher then everything should go the opposite way that's the boolean..@GeekyCoder

Answer (score 0):

In a typical logout scenario , clicking on logout button should just start the login activity clearing the login details. In your case after 5 mins you should try to clear the stored token for login ( assuming you store the login details for the user to login automatically when required). When the user launches the app next time your LAUNCHER activity would check for the stored token to launch the required activity.